# Get rid of black blinking cursor

Tags: eclipse

Today while coding on eclipse, I accidentally pressed something the cursor started blinking in black color. It's really annoying when I  backspace the wrong letters were getting erased.

Comment: Please specify your IDE etc.

Comment: Hit INSERT again... but what's this got to do with java?

Comment: I figured out how to get rid of the black blinking cursor. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VoR6GwxFkFw this link explains perfectly how to get rid of the cursor. By pressing insert again you can get rid of the blinking cursor.